# CRM 2011 plugin - get field value when not updated

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In my plugin i want to be able to get a field value, but right now I can only get it if it has been updated on the form. Currently i'm using an `entity.contains()` function and then a retrieve, but this doesn't work for just getting values in the form if the field hasn't changed.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I must have missed that part of the SDk when i was going through it. My apologies.

Comment: No worries Jimminybob, you shouldn't apologise - despite my awkward choice of words, it wasn't a challenge to you, I just couldn't understand what made your question notable enough for others to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the pre-image. The pre-image contains the entity as it was prior to the update. You can regiester a new image with the [plugin registration tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515).

Answer (score 0):

While Message is Update.All field values should be false in crm record accept that what you are Updating. for that you have to use Pre or Post Images it will directly fetch data from sql database transactions.